# whether there is no leakage of memory in QByteArray?

Tags: qt

Judging by the `QByteArray` code contains the index where bytes are stored. And the destructor is created standard, i.e. during removal of `QByteArray` the index is removed, but memory to which he points isn't released?

Comment: I suggest you learn about implicit sharing: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly did you figure that out?

```
inline QByteArray::~QByteArray() { if (!d->ref.deref()) Data::deallocate(d); }
```

Looks a lot like deallocation to me.